# Printing all switch statements

Tags: c, switch-statement

I know how to print in C, but I am just wondering if there is a quick way to execute all case statements at once so I don't have to `printf` all the menu options again. I want the user to see the menu first before choosing an option from the menu.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int menu;   
printf("Enter option : \n" );
scanf(" %c", &menu);


switch(menu)
{
        case '1':
            printf("1. Where do you live \n");
        break;

        case '2':
            printf("2. How old are you \n");
         break;

        case '3':
            printf("3. What is your name \n");
            break;

    case '4':
            printf("4. Where do you live \n");
            break;



}
return 0;
};
```

Comment: Don't put a semicolon after the close brace of a function.  It actually makes a vacuous 'variable declaration'; it is certainly not a required part of function syntax.

Comment: If you want to *unconditionally* print all the statements in your cases, why do you have the `switch` block at all?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "empty declaration" there is actually illegal in C

Comment: @MattMcNabb: OK; GCC allows it unless you force its hand with `-pedantic`; `clang` can also be persuaded to complain (`-Weverything` triggers a complaint; I am sure there is another less stringent way to get the same complaint — indeed, it is `-Wextra-semi` judging by the error message).  All the more reason for not using it.

Comment: If you want to execute *all* the cases, then why are you using `switch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There IS a way to do it.  It's fairly ugly, but you can use intentional fall throughs to execute all your case statements, so long as you force it to start on your first case.

```
if (print_all)
{
  menu = '1';
}

switch(menu)
{
        case '1':
            printf("1. Where do you live \n");

        if (!print_all)
          break;

        case '2':
            printf("2. How old are you \n");

        if (!print_all)
          break;

        case '3':
            printf("3. What is your name \n");

        if (!print_all)
          break;

        case '4':
            printf("4. Where do you live \n");

        if (!print_all)
          break;
}
```

You might also want to check out Duff's Device, which uses switches in an even more peculiar manner.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, I agree that for the OP this is probably not what he actually wants for his program, but he did unintentionally ask an interesting question.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to execute all the cases of the `switch` without making (major) modifications to it.

However in your case I don't think you need to. Move all the menu `printf`'s up above the "Enter option" `printf`, so that the menu is displayed before the prompt appears. You don't want the `printf`'s inside the `switch` statement at all! The `switch` is going to be for processing the user's response.

Comment: "There's no way to execute all the cases of a switch."  That's factually incorrect.  See my answer.